# Finding differences between dataframes while iterating a dataframe index

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to compare items in a dataframe that share same values but different columns index.

```
data1 = {'foo': [1,2,3], 'bar': [4,5,6]}
data2 = {'foo': [1,2,50], 'boo': [4,5,6]}
data1 = pd.DataFrame(data1)
data2 = pd.DataFrame(data2)
```

I'm trying to write a script that compare the values of the two dataframes based on the index.

The desired output is:

```
same
same
different

same
same
same
```

Since I should keep different column names, here is my code

```
#Input

for row in data1.index:
    if data1.iloc[row, 0] == data2.iloc[row, 0]:
        print('same')
    else:
        print('different')
```

While I can sucessfully iterate through `foo` column, I'm yet unable to iterate through `bar` and `boo`.

```
#Output 

same
same
different
```

If I try to keep only  `if data1.iloc[row]` while slicing, it throws:
`ValueError: Can only compare identically-labeled Series objects`

Do you have suggestions?
Thanks

Comment: you want to use `pandas.DataFrame.diff` https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.diff.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the dimensions match, one way is to use `numpy.where`:

```
out = np.where(data1.to_numpy() == data2.to_numpy(), 'same','different').T.tolist()
```

Output:

```
[['same', 'same', 'different'], ['same', 'same', 'same']]
```

You could also construct a DataFrame:

```
out = pd.DataFrame(np.where(data1.to_numpy() == data2.to_numpy(), 'same','different'), columns=['first_column','second_column'])
```

Output:

```
  first_column second_column
0         same          same
1         same          same
2    different          same
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using the underlying numpy array, which ignores the columns:

```
for i in range(df1.shape[1]):
    print("compare column", i)
    print(df1.iloc[:,i].to_numpy() == df2.iloc[:,i].to_numpy())
```